# how to prevent systemd from moving process to other cgroups when executing su command

Tags: systemd, pam, cgroups

Systemd provides **pam_systemd.so** for PAM module and for many commands, such as `su` command, **pam_systemd.so** will be called and the process will be moved to the cgroup that systemd managed.

Generally, if we move the bash process from its related session `cgroup` created by `systemd` under `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user.slice` to some other cgroup, then systemd will move the new bash process into a new group named as `session-cxxxx.scope` under `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user.slice` after executing `su` command.

We would like to manage the cgroups for a set of processes created by ourselves, how to prevent systemd to do such routines, without disabling pam_systemd in PAM module.

For example

the default cgroup root path is `/sys/fs/cgroup`.

When manually created 'bash' process with pid 12345 and session id 99999, then systemd will create directory `session-99999.scope` under `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user.slice/user-0.slice/` and place the process 12345 into it.

For other cgroups such as cpu or memory, the process 12345 will be placed into eache user.slice directory under these cgroups bounded with subsystems

If we move the process with pid 12345 into other cgroup from session-99999.scope, for example:

We move it from `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-99999.scope` to `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/`.

For cpu group, we move it form `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/user.slice` to `/sys/fs/cgroup/my_test_group`.

Then we execute 'su xxx' command, created a new bash with pid 13333, then

Systemd will create a new session group named `session-cxxxxx.scope`, for example, `session-c10010.scope` under `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user.slice/user-0.slice/` and place the new process 13333 into it.

For the cpu group, the new process 13333 will be placed into user.slice instead of the my_test_group.